# neo4j 2.1.5 server Failed: Error starting

Tags: neo4j

had a relatively small database that was working fine. 
then the server spiked at 99% cpu for an hour. only thing i could do is terminate the process.
now the server will not start providing the following error.

```
Starting Neo4j Server failed: Error starting
org.neo4j.kernel.EmbeddedGraphDatabase,   c:.......
```

i have since rebooted the machine.
i am running 2.1.5 community edition on a windows server.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you share your messages.log file in your database directory?

Comment: Can you also share the full error message you get?

Comment: What kind of query did you run? Btw. in Neo4j 2.2 there will be a facility for cleanly killing long running queries.

Comment: will be glad to.    Do you mean all the files with this name sequence?     
nioneo_logical.log.v0
,,,,,
nioneo_logical.log.v30

Comment: As for the query, I cant recall the exact query, but it's been one I've been executing during my learning curb :)      however it did / does include collect, filter, length,  and probably did not include a limit when it should have

Comment: No, there is a file called messages.log

Comment: I've searched the entire machine and there is no file with that name. ( OTHER than an old neo installation from March ) ;/
is the logging on by default on neo4j 2.1.5 ( windows ) ?

Comment: I did locate a console.log which seems to have a few exceptions in it.  I'm not sure is that's what you're looking for, but am glad to share it.  Let me how you'd like to receive it?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your data directory is corrupt. Go into `db/data` and rename `graph.db` to `graph.db.old`, then restart.

Comment: renaming the file did not correct the issue.
reverted to a copy a few days old.  frankly I am surprised at the fragility. ( I must be missing something )

Comment: Is it happening after a particular query? What you call "fragility," others may call "misuse." ;-)

Comment: Well hard to argue that subvertallchris :)
the fragility I was referring to was getting to the corrupt fails state.   I completely agree that the query I made that has the server spiking at 99%  was my bad. ( still don't let me make a mistake with that kind of consequences ) ( should be much harder to do that )   ")

Comment: Usually, this sort of thing is the result of a bad query. If you want to share what caused this, I'm sure we could help you figure out what the story is.